# why sizer dealing with padding value as a hight?

Tags: flutter, sizer

I am using sizer library, but i am wondering why padding value is assigned as a height `top:5.h` instead of weight `top:5.w`?.

**The code in the Sizer documentation is:**

```
 Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5.h, horizontal: 3.h),
      child: Container(),
    );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks more logical

```
Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5.h, horizontal: 3.w),
      child: Container(),
    );
```

It creates :
A vertical padding of 5% of the screen height
An horizontal padding of 3% of the screen width

It might be a mistake in the doc, you could suggest an edit on the [repo](https://github.com/TechnoUrmish/Sizer)